# Are arrays in java pass by reference or pass by value?

Tags: java, arrays, pass-by-reference

Are arrays in Java pass by reference or pass by value?

Suppose I have an array called `data` that contains objects of some type. Now let us suppose that I pass and store that array in class A and then I pass it to class B and class B changes one of the entries of the array. Will class A's version of the array change? Does it matter if this was an array of primitives (such as `int`) instead?  What about ArrayLists?

Comment: Why not simply test this? And if you have, what was your conclusion? (not my down-vote by the way)

Comment: I have no problem with  downvote :-). I agree that this is very basic question however I also asked it to myself earl in career and what official java tutor on sun (now oracle) offers is usually either very generic or very high level is java is your first programming language you are learning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything in Java is pass-by-value.  However, if you're passing a reference, it's the value of the reference.

Since Java methods can't reach into the caller's stack to reassign variables, no method call can change the identity of a reference (address) there.  This is what we mean when we say Java is not pass-by-reference.  This contrasts with C++ (and similar languages), which allows this in some cases.

Now let's look at some effects.

If I do:

```
Object[] o = ...
mutateArray(o);
```

the *contents* can be different afterwards, since all `mutateArray` needs is the address of an array to change its contents.  However, the address of `o` will be the same.  If I do:

```
String x = "foo";
tryToMutateString(x);
```

the address of `x` is again the same afterwards.  Since strings are immutable, this implies that it will also still be `"foo"`.

To mutate an object is to change the contents of it (e.g. successfully changing the last element of `o`, or trying to change the last letter of "foo" to 'd').  This should not be be confused with reassigning `x` or `o` in the caller's stack (impossible).

The Wikipedia section on [call by sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) may shed additional light.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in java is passed by value, it is confusing because when we create an object or array in java, we store the address of that object in our variable(and not the object). So when we pass that variable in a method, that method takes the address(which is a value) and store it in its local variable. any changes to the local variable will not be reflected in the original variable.
however, we can use the local variable(which contains the address of the object) to access the fields and methods of the object.
same is with the array as it is also an object.

here is how we can use all this knowledge

```
package newStart;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class JavaIsAlwaysCallByValueArray {


static void swap(int[] a,int[] b )
{
    int[] temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp; //all this is doing is swapping the address of local variables 
of this method which will not be reflected in main method 
}

static void swapThisWay(int[] a,int b[])
{
    int[] temp=new int[b.length];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)  //here we are using this variable to 
access field of array object
        temp[i]=a[i];
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    {
        a[i]=b[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        b[i]=temp[i];
    `enter code here`}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int a1[]= {1,2,4,6,8};
    int a2[]= {6,5,3,8,9};
    swap(a1,a2);
    System.out.println("just swap \na1 : "+Arrays.toString(a1)+"\na2 : 
"+Arrays.toString(a2));
    swapThisWay(a1,a2);
    System.out.println("Now \na1 : "+Arrays.toString(a1)+"\na2 : 
"+Arrays.toString(a2));
}

}
```

Answer (score -5):

Arrays, like all other objects, are pass by reference (technically, you are passing a reference by value, but from the objects point of view, it is passed by reference).  If you pass an array to a method and the method changes the array, the caller will see the changes.  If you want to avoid having your copy modified, you need to copy it yourself.  It doesn't matter whether the array contains primitives or objects.  In general, this is the behavior you want, since passing by value would involve unnecessarily copying the (potentially large) array every time you use it as an argument.

Answer (score -5):

The Jist of it is - everything in Java is passed by reference, unless it is a primitive.

Comment: I'm down-voting this, since two people already said it, and it's misleading at best.  At least Petro explained the terminology dispute.